# Is there a proposed parameter of 'copula-drop'?

Tags: linguistic-typology, principles-and-parameters, copula

There is a property of languages with respect to  copula (a verb 'to be' to mark equivalent thing): the copula may be necessary, or prohibited (and more complex mixtures of necessary and prohibited.

For example, English requires a copula:

> He is a doctor
>   (you can't take a way the 'is')

In Russian, 'is' is not allowed (but it is necessary in the past):

> On vrach. ('he doctor'..)

Is this property an accepted **primary** [parameter of language (like pro-drop, or head direction)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_and_parameters) that is, a property that is correlated with other properties? Or is it associated secondarily with one of the more common parameters?

Comment: Your Russian example is wrong. It should be "Jemu horosho" (ему хорошо). he.DAT good 'he feels good'If you meant to say "he is a good person," then it should be "on horoshij chelovek" he.NOM good.M person

Comment: @Alex: your second example fits with my other examples. Fixed. Maybe the adjective standing in for a noun is one of the related properties?

Comment: @AlexB. Wow you're right. I didn't really notice that.

Comment: There are forms of copula which are not verbs by the way. Japanese has both a verb and "something else" which seems to be a syntactic structure I don't understand. Georgian has both a verb and an enclitic.

Comment: @hippietrail As far as I know, Japanese has only the copula です/だ (**desu**, *polite*; **da**, *casual*), which is not a verb "to be" but it's also used as such.

Comment: That's what I thought until a question on japanese.SE but I'm no kind of expert: ***[What exactly is “なの” (nano)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/what-exactly-is-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE-nano)***

Comment: @hippietrail It still doesn't say it's a copula, though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alenanno: I don't know. There might be more about it in the Japanese site [under the copula tag](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copula?sort=newest).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WALS has "[Zero copula for predicate nominals](http://wals.info/chapter/120)" as [feature 120A](http://wals.info/feature/120A) and explicitly treats it as a parameter. The chapter has a thorough discussion on the subject.

In particular it talks about different types of copulas, including verbal (e.g. [English](http://wals.info/datapoint/120A/wals_code_eng)), pronominal (e.g. [Hebrew](http://wals.info/datapoint/120A/wals_code_heb)), and particle (e.g. [Kabyle](http://wals.info/datapoint/120A/wals_code_kbl)) copulas.

It also points out that zero copula forms a continuum, and not merely a binary parameter. E.g. in English, a zero copula is never allowed; in [Sinhalese](http://wals.info/datapoint/120A/wals_code_snh) a zero copula is mandatory<sup>**1**</sup>; but in [Russian](http://wals.info/datapoint/120A/wals_code_rus) a zero copula is used in the present ('**она врач**') but not the past ('**она была врачом**').

**Edit**: It appears that [Strasser (1994)](http://books.google.com/books?id=DLh8QODmcEsC&lpg=PA64&ots=C0IFMDVu3K&dq=%22zero%20copula%22%20parameter&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q&f=false) — the author of the WALS chapter — did an extensive study on zero copulas and their association with various parameters (such as Tensedness), it's just not discussed in the short WALS chapter.

---

<sup>**1**: Note that WALS refers to languages like Sinhalese, where the zero copula is compulsory, as 'zero copula possible': *«only languages of the English type have been rated as type 1. In other words, a language is considered to be a member of type 2 if it allows the use of a zero copula, however minimal...»*</sup>

Comment: Excellent reference (and it shows that I was in error for both Chinese (Mandarin) and Russian: in Chinese zero-copula is impossible, and in Russian it is mixed as you point out. In the article at WAIS, I didn't see any connection with other parameters. Did you see any there, or do you know of others that might be correlated?

Comment: Check out the book by Strasser, the author of the WAIS chapter, that I added above.

Comment: I didn't know быть would take the instrumental case, nice to know! :D By the way, nice answer, but there is something: You said that Sinhalese has a *mandatory* zero copula, but the page you linked says "Zero copula is *possible*" (emphasis mine). Am I missing something?

Comment: Alennano, in the key on the WAIS page it explains that they only map two values for copula: "impossible" (zero copula never occurs) and "possible" (zero copula can occur); "possible" includes "mandatory".

Comment: Many Slavic languages use the instrumental for a predicate noun; e.g. Polish **Jestem lekarzem** "I am a doctor".

Comment: @MarkBeadles Do you mind using the @ ? Otherwise I don't know if you reply. :D Anyway, in my opinion there is a difference between "possible" and "mandatory". In the former case, it can occur (or not), in the latter it always occurs. It would be more precise to write that, rather than mandatory. But apart from this, I like your answer.

Comment: @Alenanno I agree with your opinion the terminology; WAIS is the one with the strange terms :) I will add some text to my answer to clarify.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thanks! I slightly fixed some formatting in your footnote. +1 from me!

Comment: The Strasser reference seems to say that, though it is associated with other parameters...it is complicated. That is I think the explanation is complicated, not that necessarily it is complicated.

Comment: I think there's an issue of terminology; the contributions to WALS are all from outside the Chomskyan framework, so if the word "parameter" gets mentioned in a WALS chapter (as with chapter 120), it should not be understood in quite the same sense as "Parameter" when used by linguists from the Principles and Parameters framework. There is, for example, no WALS map plotting the "head directionality" Parameter setting for different languages, but there are instead a large number of chapters on general word order patterns.

Comment: @jlovegren, yes that is a good point on reflection. In which case this answer's not directly responsive in the sense the questioner might have been looking for. Though I think it is suggestive that zero-copula (or equivalent) could be treated as a Parameter, I haven't introduced any evidence that anyone has so suggested.